# OpenCV top predictions for face

Tags: opencv

The use of OpenCV is fairly simple- create a `FaceRecognizer` object, train it, give it a source of images and then check your given image against those images with regards to the trained Eigenimage.

The problem is, the `predict` method has only two modes- find a match, or find a match and get the confidence of that match.

What I'd like to do is instead get a list of, say, the top ten matches along with the confidences of them (often my reference images are of low quality/lighting and therefore I don't expect there to be many high-confidence matches, but rather many low-quality matches).

Answer (score 0):

If your `opencv_contrib` version is newer than 19 Jan, you can. This was merged in 19 Jan ([#465](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/pull/465)).

To use it:

```
Mat testImage = ...; // load your test image

Ptr<TopNPredictCollector> collector = TopNPredictCollector.create(10, THRESH);
model->predict(testImage, collector);
Ptr<std::list<std::pair<int,double>>> result = collector.getResult();
```

Before that, the only colletor available was `MinDistancePredictCollector()`, that's why you could only get the closest match ([see here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/commit/9ff3192ea567b027e5514d1e025b3e6b3ce34643)).